# How to get null counts of each rows except one column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Name': ['Smith', Null, Null,'Joy'], 
               'First_Name': ['John', Null, 'Bill', 'Tony'],
               'Age': [35, 45, Null, 60]})
```

How can I get the null counts of only `First_Name` and `Age` and not `Last_Name`? I am doing something like below but it is fetching all null counts of all columns.

```
null_counts = irs_df.isnull().sum()
null_counts[null_counts > 0].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

How to filter out `Last_Name`?

Answer (score 6):

You can select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
null_counts = irs_df.iloc[:, 1:].isnull().sum()
print (null_counts)
First_Name    1
Age           1
dtype: int64
```

Or remove column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
null_counts = irs_df.drop('Last_Name', axis=1).isnull().sum()
print (null_counts)
First_Name    1
Age           1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have 50 columns. Cant I mention the name of the variable and filter out ?

Comment: @Rahul - Like second solution?

Comment: yeah..Second is fine. I will try this one. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to `df.drop` would be to use [`DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on the columns to remove the column that isn't of interest:

```
null_counts = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['Last_Name'])].isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
print (null_counts)
Age           1
First_Name    1
dtype: int64
```

A quick comparison of timings between `drop` and `isin` approaches on a much larger dataframe suggests there's not a lot in it.

Answer (score 0):

#### `count`

Counts the non-nulls.  So subtract it from the length of the dataframe

```
(len(df) - df.count()).drop('Last_Name')

First_Name    1
Age           1
dtype: int64
```